# Why exception is not caught this way in async function in Dart?

Tags: dart, async-await

```dart
Future<void> fetchUserOrder() async {
// Imagine that this function is fetching user info but encounters a bug
  try {
  return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => throw Exception('Logout failed: user ID is invalid'));
    
  } catch(e) {
    // Why exception is not caught here?
    print(e);
  }
}

void main() {
  fetchUserOrder();
  print('Fetching user order...');
}
```

It outputs

```
Fetching user order...
Uncaught Error: Exception: Logout failed: user ID is invalid
```

Which says the exception is not caught. But as you see, the `throw Exception` clause is surrounded by try catch.

Comment: You can try the code here: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The try-catch block will only catch exception of **awaited** Future. So you have to use `await` in your code:

```dart
Future<void> fetchUserOrder() async {
// Imagine that this function is fetching user info but encounters a bug
  try {
  return await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => throw Exception('Logout failed: user ID is invalid'));
    
  } catch(e) {
    // Why exception is not caught here?
    print(e);
  }
}

void main() {
  fetchUserOrder();
  print('Fetching user order...');
}
```