# Dart: `return future` vs `async return future`

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm running this code:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  final c = Future.value(); // Other constructors and `Completer.future` all yield same results.
 
  print(c == sync(c));
  print(c == aSync(c));
}

Future sync(Future future) {
  return future;
}

Future aSync(Future future) async {
  return future;
}
```

And I get as output a seemingly strange result:

```
true
false
```

I know how futures work in Dart, and that technically we create a new `Future` instance for every `async` function, but it just seems strange how we return the same object in both cases, yet with different results.

Is this intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected behavior.  One of the things that the `async` keyword does is to transform `return` statements in the function body to return `Future`s.  If the function body already returns a `Future`, don't be surprised if it gets transformed into a *new* `Future`.

What's *supposed* to happen is that an existing `Future` directly returned within an `async` function is implicitly `await`ed.  That is:

```dart
Future<T> aSync<T>(Future<T> future) async {
  return future;
}
```

is supposed to be equivalent to:

```dart
Future<T> aSync<T>(Future<T> future) async {
  return await future;
}
```

Apparently this is what's intended by the Dart language specification but isn't what happens in practice.  [Not having the implicit `await` can make error-handling confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70196704/) if the `Future` fails.

[There also is discussion about disallowing `async` functions from directly returning `Future`s](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/870) and to require that they explicitly `await` any returned `Future`s instead.